# Setting cells height gives me error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UIView` in a `UITableViewCell`. I'm trying to change the height of the `view` with an animation. Here is what I did:

```
self.myViewConstraint.constant = 100; // Coming from 0
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];        
    }];
```

The only thing is, it's in a `tableView`. So here's what I did for the `heightForRow...`:

```
return self.myViewConstraint.constant == 0 ? 74 : 174;
```

Now I need to update the `tableView`, so I inserted in `animateWithDuration`:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Because I have other things inside the the `cell`, so the `constraints` get messed up while the `cells` height is animating. How can I update the `cells` height without getting the constraints messed up? (I want the `cells` height to animate.)

Here is the warning I get. (Everything works fine, but I just want to remove the warning.)

**Edit** I changed it a bit, and I now get this error:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8d62d15670 V:[tagResultTableView:0x7f8d62d901a0(107)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8d62cea010 tagResultTableView:0x7f8d62d901a0.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8d62d8fd50.topMargin - 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8d62cf0760 V:[tagResultTableView:0x7f8d62d901a0]-(8)-[UILabel:0x7f8d62d2e2e0'Limit: Up to 5 tags']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8d62cf0800 UILabel:0x7f8d62d2e2e0'Limit: Up to 5 tags'.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8d62d8fd50.bottomMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8d62f726d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8d62d8fd50(32)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8d62d15670 V:[tagResultTableView:0x7f8d62d901a0(107)]>
```

Comment: Can you post the constraint for `myViewConstraint ` please?

Comment: It's a height constraint

Comment: everything is not working fine because you have having auto layout conflicts... remember the autolayout engine is calculating the frame, so when you change one constraint, others are also changing. You have to keep them in sync. Seems your contents in the cell cannot adapt to the change. Maybe check if something wrong in your contents' layout setup.

Comment: It looks fine. And it only happens when I add the animation

Comment: Try `[UITableView reloadData]`, and do the animation in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: you can use EstimatedHeightRow

Comment: @user3480295 Can you please show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return self.myViewConstraint.constant == 0 ? 74 : 174;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ReuseID];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ReuseID];
    }
    if (self.myViewConstraint.constant != 0) {
        [cell doAnimation];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do I set the constraint in another method?

Comment: Yes, and call `[UITableView reloadData]` after that.

Comment: And what is [cell doAnimation]? Shouldn't it be [self doAnimation]?

Comment: Both are ok. But I think it would be better to do animation inside the cell.

Comment: It works only when setting the constraint from 100 to 0, but not from 0 to 100. (I will need to do both.) And I removed the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

1. Create a custom `UITableViewCell` and create an outlet for the height contentView of for the 'CustomView'
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
   and set all your constraints.
2. In `viewDidLoad` set the following

   `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`
   `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = N; // N is some estimated height of your cells`
3. Animate the height by changing the `IBOutlet` constant in `updateContraints` method `heightConstraint.constant = newHeight` to do this, whenever you need to update the height of your `UIView`, you can have

   `[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations: ^{ 
       [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded] // This will call to updateContraints you should calculate the new height inside that method
    }];`
4. Finally call to

   `[tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I changed around the views a bit. I still get an error. It may be a slightly different error, but it's still the same problem.

Comment: Also, a minor thing: I think there is a small typo. Instead of self.contentView, I think it should be self.view