# Add object on a tableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In the `storyboard` I have a `static UItableViewController`. I want to add a `tableView` on top of that `tableVC`. So I created a custom class that's a subclass of `UITableViewController`. Here's that code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.bounds = self.textField.bounds;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma mark - TableView delegate
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.resultArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    [cell.textLabel setText:self.resultArray [indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Then in the main `viewControllers` class I did the following:

```
resultTableVC *tableView = [[resultTableVC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.textField = self.tagsTextField;

[self.view addSubview:tableView.tableView];
```

When I run the app, I get the following error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<mainTableViewController 0x7fe35a550530> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tagResultView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102182c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101e1bbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001021828a9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001019b1b53 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001020cad50 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000102a9552b -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001028ed718 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001028edd08 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000102ab1df8 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 76
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001028edf79 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001028ee40e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000102ab1b73 -[UITableViewController tableView] + 30
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000102ab25ba -[UITableViewController _viewControllerWasSelected] + 22
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010292cf46 -[UITabBarController viewDidAppear:] + 140
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001028f1ff1 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 567
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001028f2b3b -[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 52
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001027e162c _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 314
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001027e14c5 _afterCACommitHandler + 564
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001020b5ca7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001020b5c00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001020aba33 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001020ab366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000105fe8a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    23  UIKit                               0x00000001027bd900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    24  myBudget                            0x00000001013a852f main + 111
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000103bd9145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I don't know what the error means, or how to fix it. (If this isn't correct) What's the proper way to add a `tableView` on top of an existing `tableViewController`?

Comment: Could you describe how a tableView on top of another tableView is supposed to work?  What are you aiming for, in the final version, functionality-wise?  It seems like there's probably a simpler way of achieving the same effect.

Comment: I'm trying to create a autoComplete UITextField. I know there are other library's that offer this, but I didn't find any that's compatible with a UITabelViewController.

Comment: Ah.  Well I don't know that it would be causing this problem, but at least one thing that will trip you up: when you create the `resultTableVC` and add its tableView to the main view (`[self.view addSubview:tableView.tableView];`), you need to hold onto the `resultTableVC` in an instance variable, or similar.  I had a similar problem: I would create a ViewController, add its View to the main page, but it would crash.  Turns out the View was being kept in memory, but the ViewController itself was being released, so it broke.  That might be a second problem, though.

Comment: So what should I do to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because there is no property called `tagResultView`. There is bad link to a `mainTableViewController` object that probably is specifying tagResultView. Check your storyboard/xib and remove any link to the undefined key specified(`tagResultView`). This happens when you remove something from the view controller improperly or when you rename views.

For creating an autocomplete `UITextField` I don't think you need to add a `UITableView` to another `UITableView`, Why not trying to have `UIView` or `CustomTextField` that will contain a `UITextField` and a `UITableView` for the autocomplete stuff then with the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol you can present the `UITableView` anywhere you want it using `Autolayout`. Then just create a `UITableViewCell` and add the `CustomTextField` to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That solved the problem! The reason why I can't do what you said is because I will have problems with the animation. I posted a question on that yesterday and didn't get the right response.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127922/setting-cells-height-gives-me-error If you have a solution to that, I would really appreciate that!